# $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\sqrt{-1}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, definition

I have trouble to comprehend what my mistake is in the following calculation:

If we set $\sqrt{-1}$ to be the new number with the property that $(\sqrt{-1})^2 = -1$ then I can write $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{-1}}=\sqrt{-1}.$$

But we also have (and I know this is the correct result) $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{-1}=-\sqrt{-1}$$

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Every nonzero complex number has **two** square roots.

Comment: The identity $\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$ is not true in general for complex numbers.

Comment: $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$ is a little white lie we tell our selves when we assume we are only dealing with real numbers. Well one of two. In truth we only know that $|\sqrt{|ab|}|=|\sqrt{|a|}||\sqrt{|b|}|$. this is a white lie for reals as only positive numbers have square roots and we only consider that positive square root.

Comment: For real numbers only $x\ge 0$ have square roots.  So if we see $\sqrt{ab}$ we *assume* $ab\ge 0$ which means either $a\ge 0; b\ge 0$ or $a<0;b<0$ but in either case $ab = (-a)(-b) = |a||b|$ so we *assume* $a\ge 0;b\ge 0$.  And in that case $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ that assumes only real numbers $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{(-a)(-b)}\ne\sqrt{-a}\sqrt{-b}$ because negatives don't have square roots.  In reality we have $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{|a|}\sqrt{|b|}$ but *ONLY* with the assumption $ab \ge 0$.  Now if we assume that we can have square roots of negative numbers *LOTS* of things go out the window.....

Comment: To begin with if $x = a^2$ then $x=(-a)^2$ so ever number has two square roots. One is $\sqrt{x}$, the other is $-\sqrt{x}$.  That's true even if $x=a^2$ if $a$ isn't real or $x$ isn't positive. If $\sqrt{-1}=i$ exists then we can't say that $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b};\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{-a*-b}=\sqrt{-a}\sqrt{-b}=i\sqrt{a}i\sqrt{b}=i^2\sqrt{ab}=-\sqrt{ab}$.  It isn't true that $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$.  Instead it's only $|\sqrt{ab}|=|\sqrt{a}||\sqrt{b}|$.

Comment: So the second way works.  But the first way doesn't.  It's interesting but.  $\frac 1{\sqrt{-1}} = -\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: And it's interesting that $i^1 = i; i^2 = -1; i^3 = -i = \frac 1i$ and $i^4 = (i^2)^2 = i^3*i =1$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is due to the use of the same symbol $\sqrt{\cdot}$ with different meanings.

Let's separate the meanings by distinguishing:

- $\sqrt[\text{real}]{\cdot}$ is an operator defined on non-negative real numbers, that associates to $x$ the unique non-negative real number $y$ such that $y \cdot y = x$;
- $\sqrt[\text{new}]{-1}$ is a symbol used to indicate a new number, that satisfies the property $\sqrt[\text{new}]{-1}\cdot \sqrt[\text{new}]{-1} = -1$.

The first chain of equations you wrote translates to:

$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt[\text{new}]{-1}}=\frac{\sqrt[\text{real}]{1}}{\sqrt[\text{new}]{-1}} \overset{!}{=} \frac{\sqrt[\text{real}]{1}}{\sqrt[\text{real}]{-1}} \overset{!}{=} \sqrt[\text{real}]{\frac{1}{-1}} \overset{!}{=} \sqrt[\text{real}]{-1},$$

but the steps marked with $\overset{!}{=}$ are not valid since $\sqrt[\text{real}]{-1}$ is not defined.

Comment: This would be almost perfect if you added the word *positive* when necessary. Also, the equations at the end make no sense, because $\sqrt[\text{real}]{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: I have to point out that this misses the point. $\sqrt[\text{real}]{x}$ is *NOT* unique.  If $y*y=x$ then $(-y)(-y)=x$.  Nor is $\sqrt[\text{new}]{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I tried to fix my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The incorrect step is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{-1}}$$
This kind of relations that you learned very soon in your life are so anchored in your thinking that you don't even think that they need to be re-checked whenever the settings are different. Complex numbers behave differently to positive real numbers in that respect.